# If $Y$ is a proper closed subspace of a Hilbert space $H$, how do you prove the existence of some $f \in H'$ with the properties below?

Tags: functional-analysis

If $x_0 \in H - Y$ and $\delta = \inf_{y \in Y} \|y - x_0\|$ then there exists $f \in H'$ such that $$\|f\|=1, \quad f(y)=0 \,\,\text{for all} \,\,y\in Y, \quad f(x_0)=\delta .$$

So far all I have is that $H= Y \bigoplus Z$, where $Z$ is the orthogonal complement of $Y$, and every $x \in H$ has the unique representation $y + z$. I'm stuck with how to define $f$ that will yield the desired properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Riesz' Theorem (for the representation of functionals) tells us that every bounded linear functional on a Hilbert space $H$ is of the form $$f(x) = \langle x,z \rangle$$ for some fixed $z \in H$ where $\|z\| = \|f\|$. Then the problem is equivalent to the existence of $z \in H$ such that the given conditions are satisfied. (Really all we need to answer the problem is that the inner product with one term fixed defines a bounded linear functional but knowing that all bounded linear functionals are of this form helps to know where to look).

We know that there is (unique) $y_0 \in Y$ such that $\|x_0-y_0\| = \delta$. We also know that $z' = x_0 - y_0$ is orthogonal to $Y$. This orthogonality condition is a strong hint that something like $z'$ is a good candidate to define our functional.

Note that $\|z\| = \|f\|$ means that our choice of $z$ must have norm $1$ so we choose $z = \frac{1}{\delta}(x_0 - y_0)$. Then $z$ is orthogonal to $Y$ and $\|z\| = 1$.

Finally $1 = \bigg \|\frac{1}{\delta}(x_0 - y_0) \bigg \|^2 = \frac{1}{\delta^2}(\langle x_0, x_0-y_0 \rangle - \langle y_0, x_0 - y_0 \rangle) = \frac{1}{\delta} \langle x_0, \frac{1}{\delta}(x_0 - y_0) \rangle$ which gives us $f(x_0) = \langle x_0, z \rangle = \delta$.

So the linear functional defined by $f(x) = \langle x, \frac{1}{\delta}(x_0-y_0) \rangle$ satisfies the desired conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.